# page redirect without showing scroll behavior in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I want to direct open to the top without scrolling. You can visit https://react.dev/learn/react-developer-tools, this page when I click the side nav, in this case, opens the top of the page without scrolling. Just, I want this functionality.

```
useEffect(() => window.scrollTo(0, 0), []);
```

I have tried it but it shows scrolling behavior.

Comment: Show the rest of the component, you probably need to call that when you change content, not on mount of the component

Answer (score 0):

scrollTo accepts on "options" parameter.  behavior options are "smooth", "instant", and "auto".  provide a "behavior" property of "instant" to avoid animation when scrolling.  example:

```
window.scrollTo({ top: 0, left: 0, behavior: 'instant' })
```

docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollTo